# How can I call localhost from localhost (laravel, nodejs)?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, networking, localhost

I am writing an application with node and laravel. I am running small laravel local server which resolves to http://localhost:8000. i am also running a node server on localhost:3000. Then trying to call the first server from the second. Here is the NodeJs code:

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Here is where I make the http request:

```
var http = require('http');


module.exports = {
    call: function (host, path) {
        var options = {
          host: host,
          path: path,
          port: 8000,
          method: 'GET'
        };

        callback = function(response) {
          var str = '';

          response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
          });

          response.on('end', function () {
            return str;
          });
        }

        http.request(options, callback).end();
    }
}
```

This is the actual call I am making:

```
httpCaller.call('http://localhost', '/fire');
```

I get the following response on the command line:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://localhost http://localhost:8000
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

I tried removing http:// and just calling local host, and got the following:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `http.get` function?

```
http.get('http://localhost:8000/fire', (res) => {
  console.log(`Got response: ${res.statusCode}`);
  // consume response body
  res.resume();
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```